# how to allow only 1 forward slash in regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex expression to check alpha numeric inputs max 16 which is following

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,16}$
```

how i can modify this to check it should have only 1 forward slash. like

aas/as12

12/saad

Comment: your title says only 1 forwardslash but your question says at least 1 forward slash. Can there be more than one?

Comment: only 1 @ChrisDoyle sorry I updated

Comment: @Asad Just to be clear "only 1" means either 0 or 1? Or always exactly 1?

Comment: exactly 1 @Ivar

Comment: your expression says illegal escape on \d @JvdV

Comment: Note that your pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,16}$` can also match an empty string due to the quantifier. So if there should be a single `/` present `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9\/]{1,17}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` https://regex101.com/r/sWlqt4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird you expression works but if we  want slash at somewhere middle i mean not at start or end

Comment: @Asad then it would be like this `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9\/]{1,17}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/CjKZ5n/1

Comment: thanks so much you can put this into answer @Thefourthbird

Comment: and short brief will be appreciated , thanks so much @Thefourthbird

Comment: So in javascript `(?i)` isn't supported. Try `/^(?!.{17})[a-z\d]+\/[a-z\d]+$/gi`, however you allready got a more precise answer. Note: Depending on your requirements you may want to change the `{17}` into `{18}` since the forward slash would be an extra character on top of the 16 alphanumeric characters you allow.

Comment: @Thefourthbird You only have to check length in your lookahead, something like (?=.{3,16}$) for your expression.

Comment: @JvdV I think your pattern makes it a better answer, can you post that one?

Comment: your answer says invalid escape character in string at `\d`

Comment: @JvdV It is a shorter pattern, and I think the negative lookahead fails faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?!.{17})[a-z\d]+\/[a-z\d]+$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/npPwmf/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!.{17})` - Negative lookahead to prevent 17 characters (other than newline). This can be more precise *and* you may want to change into 18 depending if you count the forward slash on top of the 16 alphanumeric characters.
- `[a-z\d]+\/[a-z\d]+` - 1+ Alphanumeric chars, a single literal forward slash and again 1+ alphanumeric chars.
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Note that I used case-insensitive matches, meaning your JS-pattern would look like:

```
/^(?!.{17})[a-z\d]+\/[a-z\d]+$/gi
```

```js
const regex = /^(?!.{17})[a-z\d]+\/[a-z\d]+$/i;
[
  "aas/as12",
  "12/saad",
  "/"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
)
```

Comment: have to use double slash like this
`^(?!.{17})[a-z\\d]+\/[a-z\\d]+$`

Comment: @Asad You can use a literal, you only have to double escape the `\\d` when using the RegExp constructor.